# Is it possible to get even more detailed errors on Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on a project with VS for Mac 2022. I'm getting an error like " exited with code 1."

Is it possible to get a more detailed view of this error?
Double-clicking the error takes me to Xamarin.Shared.Targets, but it's hard to know exactly what fails.

**Is there a log output for VS for Mac, or a way to make errors more verbose?**
I've already set Preferences>Build and Debug>Build>Log verbosity to Diagnostic.